# Can I prevent postfix from sending to specific email addresses using the check_recipient_access postfix option?

Tags: postfix, mail-command

I tried to block some email addresses from spammers, but this setup doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/bad_recipients,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    ...
```

The emails are still forwarded. Here is an example of the bad_recipients file I have:

```
# When updating, make sure to run this command once:
#    postmap hash:/etc/postfix/bad_recipients

spammer@example.com REJECT
```

When I do a mail to that email address, it still gets forwarded.

```
alexis $ mail -s "Verify block" spammer@example.com
Cc:

Not much of interest here.
^D
```

When I look at the logs I see something like this:

> Mar  5 20:02:37 do postfix/smtp[8882]: E827740ADA: to=,
>   relay=mail.example.com[10.0.0.13]:25, delay=2.3, delays=0.03/0.01/1.8/0.41,
>   dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host mail.example.com[10.0.0.13] said: 550 5.7.1
>   No such user! (in reply to RCPT TO command))

*Note: I edited the domain name and IP address.*

The relaying to the external source clearly shows that my `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` settings did not block anything. I'm thinking that either it only accepts domains (although I think [the doc examples here](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html) say otherwise) or I have something else that tells postfix to ignore my list of recipient restrictions. Do you know how to make this feature work?

Answer (score 0):

Okay! [I found the answer](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/postfix-outgoing-email-blacklist-861136/).

The fact is that it works only if the user attempts to send an email using SMTP. So when using tools such as `sendmail` or `mail`, postfix ignores that entry because there is no `RCPT TO <address>` to check. This is a problem for some of my tools, fortunately, the one I want to block at the moment uses SMTP so I'm covered. Only I can't test whether it works using the `mail` command line.